# Git-Gui: Committed code but my github account shows nothing

Tags: github, git-gui

so I committed some code today for the first time to github.

however, when I go to my activity, nothing shows? What happened to the code I committed? Is there an error or log I can view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Commit* is local thing in git (works only on your local clone; that is how distributed VCSes like git or mercurial work), you should *push* to get it into github (or wherever the origin is).

Comment: okay its asking for keyphrase? I generated one and named it to id_rsa and put it in the directory it's looking for. I enter the keyphrase and it says public key and will not push.

Comment: You should setup github so it knows your ssh keys. It has a section somewhere exactly for that in the help section.

Comment: I've added the public key genreated by puttygen and saved the private key to the .ssh folder. i also accepted github's ssh key....I get `Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: Well, I don't know what may be the problem :-/ Google for what the exact error message means. Maybe try to generate the keys again, adhering to some guide (like that one on github help)... or file another question here :-)